# Is it bad to charge an iPhone 5S with an iPad Air's charger?

Tags: battery-charging, iphone

Often in the little leaflets that come with chargeable electronic gadgets, manufacturers state that you should only use the original supplied charger to charge the gadget.

We all know that an iPhone does get charged with an iPad's charger, but does this have any bad side effects? For example, would it lower the life expectancy of the battery on the iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the requirements for charging of each of your devices. If the iPad air's charger can supply at least or greater the wattage (or amperage) since they use the same voltage then yes the air can charge the iPhone.

For example my ipad2 charger can supply up to 10 watts for charging the iPad, but my iphone 5 only needs 5 watts so I can use that charger no problem, the iPhone wil only take the 5 watts it needs.  Going reverse and using the iPhone charger for the iPad could overheat the iPhone charger!

Comment: And doing that has no 'bad implications' on the iPhone battery?

Comment: The chargers supplied with my iPhone 5 and iPad mini are identical.

Comment: @ Ciwan - if the chargers are the same then this is a moot point, but if they are different and as I explained above, then No, no negative or bad implications for the iPhone battery.  The chargers for devices only provides some voltage (5 volts) and amperage.  The actual phone or ipad itself does all of the actually charging via a CC/CV algorithim so you are just supplying the energy via the plug in - the phone and the ipad take care of the rest.  Hope this helps.